# class_type column of system function "sys.fn_get_audit_file" returns null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, audit

I implemented audit in SQL Server 2019. Also I have created a job to save audit records from file to a table.
According the microsoft document column class_type is `NOT NULL`. so in my table is `NOT NULL` too. But today my job failed with the following error message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'class_type',

First of all I think this is my fault and the query has problem.
Then I discovered that really the function `sys.fn_get_audit_file` returns NULL for three statement that are `GRANT PERMISSION`.

Although I can filter these three transaction to continue saving audit record. But this conflict between [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#tables-returned) and actual data makes me anxious.

Edit:
Additional information is that the execution of these statements completed with errors. Because the object names were incorrect.

Comment: If you’re having a problem with a query you should post the query you’re having a problem with.

Comment: `sp_describe_first_result_set` returns `is_nullable: 1` for that column, so probably the docs are wrong. Some of the other columns also don't seem to match. But we'd need to see your query to be sure it's not something there.

Comment: @Charlieface My query is a simple SELECT statement from sys.fn_get_audit_file

Comment: @ErikDarling SELECT * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file (params) Where class_type is null -- This will return 3 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_describe_first_result_set` returns `is_nullable: 1` for that column, so presumably the documentation is wrong. Some of the other columns also don't seem to match.

You can make a pull request [on GitHub here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/639f03c3a1a633ace249a4b54223c664a9464294/docs/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql.md) to change the docs.

Exactly why it's returning `null`, or what the meaning of that should be, is unclear.